# Help choosing between decimated and reduced

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a question for which I am doubtful about which to choose among the two .. can someone help?

**Please select one option for the blank:**

> After years of unchecked exploitation of its natural resources, the state, predictably, has _________ the population of its native plants and animals.
>
> a) stymied
> b) increased
> c) reduced
> d) normalized
> e) decimated

I chose [decimated](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decimated) as that is strong as the question says years of exploitation.

Will any other answer fit here? Will *reduce* fit in?
I did not choose *reduce* as it is lighter than *decimated*...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your selection of *decimated* is indeed the best option here.

*Reduced* would imply that the decrease was the result of an intentional policy, which seems unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

*Reduced* could be an option, if *decimated* was not on the list.  "Reduced" is a rather mild term which just indicates a reduction in number, while "decimated" is a very strong one indicating an extreme change.  The phrase "unchecked exploitation" in the first sentence is a *very* strong wording, so one would expect a similarly strong wording in the second part.  "Decimated" is simply a better choice, and with multiple choice questions you must always choose the best choice.

If I may use recent current events, using "reduced" in this situation is similar to saying "Ebola is a highly contagious, life threatening disease with no known cure.  It is *mildly important* to avoid people who have it."  While technically accurate, I would expect the second sentence to be more along the lines of, "It is *essential to your well-being* to avoid people who have it."